# Disable/Hide chrome's close button but put functionality elsewhere

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm planning to use chrome to make app-like window using --app="url" switch.

However, I would like to put the close functionality elsewhere, can I hide/disable chrome's close button(*knowing they can end it still using task manager, they aren't technically inclined btw*)?

This is to prevent user from closing the window while logged in in the app.

(*they can close the app if already logged out or session expired*)

ADVANCE THANKS! :)

Comment: You want the user to only be able to leave your website by using the Task Manager? No, there's not a way to do that.

Comment: No, i don't want them to close the window that way. I want them to be able to close it when they are already logged out of the webapp inside the window. but until they are still logged in, i'm hoping to hide/disabable the close button. @samiles

Comment: Nah, you can't disable button in the browser. You could catch the event when they leave the page, and present them with an alert box asking them to confirm they want to leave the page (this about when you've typed something in a text box on a page and are asked to confirm leaving), but Chrome offers no way to directly disable basic browser buttons.

Comment: Is that so? Your suggestion (alert box on beforeunload event) still gives them option to Leave or Stay. Anyway, many thanks for your time! Hoping to have this feature soon if possible. @samiles :)

Comment: Yeah, my suggestion clearly isn't perfect. But think of the spam/ads/popup/malware consequences - allowing the web developer to randomly disable the close button and trust them not to misuse it is **never** going to happen.

Comment: just to add: I was just planning to use this on a LAN or enterprise based/deployed app fyi @samiles

Comment: Then you could create your own fork of Chrome and develop the feature yourself. Or look into running a web browser in "Kiosk Mode".

Comment: Yeah maybe I'll give creating the feature myself a try. BTW, I've seen kiosk mode but I don't want them to go full screen just for my app, fyi just in case u missed, they can still close the tab/s in kiosk mode using 'ctrl+w' or 'shift + Esc' then end a tab there. @samiles thanks for your time bud :)